# When dealing with tensor products, is it necessary to check the morphisms are well defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products, universal-property

For example, if I would like to show that for real vector spaces $U$, $V$ and $W$,  $\left(U\oplus V\right)\otimes W \cong\left(U\otimes W \right) \oplus \left(V\otimes W\right)$, is it enough to consider the map $f:\left(U\oplus V\right)\times W \to \left(U\otimes W \right) \oplus \left(V\otimes W\right) $ defined by $f((u,v),w)=(u\otimes w, v\otimes w)$ and extending bilinearity. If we check that it is well defined, then $f$ induces a linear map $\tau :\left(U\oplus V\right)\otimes W \to\left(U\otimes W \right) \oplus \left(V\otimes W\right)$, and then show $\ker(\tau)=\{0\}$?

Comment: The function $f$ is clearly well defined, because the rule $f((u,v),w)=(u\otimes w,v\otimes w)$ does not depend on the choice of representatives. We usually have to worry about the well definedness when the domain is a quocient.

Comment: But I guess it is necessary to check its well definedness after extending bilinearity?

Comment: @wanwuwi: We just appeal to the theorem that says that bilinear functions on $U \times V \to W$ are in one-to-one correspondence with linear functions $U \otimes V \to W$. This is the standard -- the most common way to define a linear function on a tensor product is by writing down the corresponding bilinear function (the bilinear function is could be defined pointwise, but any method will do).

Comment: This is just applying the universal property of the tensor product, which is arguably the most important elementary fact about tensor products (if it isn't literally your definition of "tensor product").